# Update Windows 10 Home to Pro without activating it

Tags: windows-10, licensing

Can you upgrade an activated Windows 10 Home edition to the Pro edition and run it for some time without activating it? If yes, when will it stop working without activation? After that, can you easily downgrade back to Windows 10 Home?

Alternatively, can the upgrade 10 Home >>> 10 Pro be performed with a Windows 7 Pro license (which was installed on another machine).

Comment: Once upgrade to Windows 10 Profesional you cannot downgrade to Windows 10 Home.  In order to upgrade to Windows 10 Professional a valid license to Windows 10 Professional must be provided.  What you want is not possible.

Comment: It is possible to install Windows 10 Pro as a trial.

Comment: @TOOGAM: for how long?

Comment: @PierreB - Windows does not actually have a trial mode.  Microsoft offers free VM for software testing, which are trials, but those can’t be activated.  Windows is either inactivated or activated.  Windows isn’t free.